# Getting 60hz on 4k display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, hdmi

I thought I did my research but I can't get my new Macbook to squeeze out 60hz to my monitor.

**Setup:**

Macbook Pro 2016 running High Sierra (15", Radeon Pro 450 2GB, 2.6 GHz i7, 16GB ram)

Dell P2415Q (Supports 60hz at 4k)

Satechi HDMI to USB-C cable (Supports 60hz at 4k)

Why can't I get 60hz on my monitor with this setup? I've even tried to force it up with SwitchResX but no luck.

**Update**

Okay, so I think I've found the problem myself. On this [page](http://www.dell.com/support/article/dk/da/dkbsdt1/sln306595/setting-up-p2415q--p2715q-monitors-with-hdmi-20-support-4k-x-2k-60hz?lang=en), Dell states:

> Dell P2415Q and P2715Q flat panel displays purchased before March 2016, only support HDMI 1.4 and provide 4k x 2k (3840 x 2160 pixels) resolution @ 30 Hz using the HDMI cable connection. 4k x 2k @60Hz is available via DisplayPort connection on these displays.

Soooo, off to my cable provider once again to get a DisplayPort to USB-C cable instead.

Comment: Did the DisplayPort cable solve the problem?

Comment: Yep, worked with 60hz as soon as the cable was plugged in.

Comment: Do you notice unusual heating when you connect the P2415Q, I lost one aged Macbook due to the heating after I connect P2415Q, if you noticed something abnormal, I'm going to avoid High Sierra (it was an issue that manifested itself after High Sierra)

Comment: Fortunately not.